Movie about aliens who are disguised as the inhabitants of an Old West town
I remember some sci-fi horror b-movie about this family who passes by some strange Old West town and it turns out the entire town is inhabited by these green aliens disguised as humans. I’m not sure it’s been a lot time since I’ve seen it.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you watch this? And to clarify the aliens were disguised as the people living in the town, not disguised as the town itself, right?

What does Old West mean? Was this set in the 19th century or was it just an old town in the western States? When was this set?
